# Spell checking - noisy channel model with java streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, spell-checking

I have a list of query logs with entries that look like this:

```
Session ID Query
01 Movie atcor
01 Movie actor
02 Award winning axtor
02 Award winning actor
03 Soap opera axtor
03 Soap opera actor
...
```

I need to determine the probability of a spelling suggestion being correct. For example, if I wanted to determine the probability of "actor" being the correct spelling for "axtor," I would compute this by determining the number of sessions in which "axtor" was replaced by "actor," divided by the number of sessions in which "actor" was the correct spelling of any *mispelled word*.

That means that in this case, the probability would be 2/3 since there are two sessions in which "actor" replaces "axtor" and three sessions where "actor" replaces a mispelling ("atcor" and "axtor").

I'm trying to familiarize myself with Java 8 streams a little more, so I am trying to get the solution using streams.

Here is what I've been able to come up with. It's a step in the right direction, but I am still missing some pieces.

```
public int numberOfCorrections(String misspelledWord, String suggestedWord)
{
    return (int) sessionIdsWithWord(misspelledWord)
            .stream()
            .map(sessionId -> getLogsWithSameSessionId(sessionId)
                    .stream()
                    .filter(queryLog -> queryLog.queryContainsWord(suggestedWord))
                    .count()
            ).count();
}

public Set<String> sessionIdsWithWord(String word)
{
    return getQueryLogsThatContainWord(word)
            .stream()
            .map(QueryLog::getSessionId)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}

public List<QueryLog> getQueryLogsThatContainWord(String word)
{
    return logs
            .stream()
            .filter(queryLog -> queryLog.queryContainsWord(word))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public Map<String, List<QueryLog>> getSessionIdMapping()
{
    return logs
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(QueryLog::getSessionId));
}

public List<QueryLog> getLogsWithSameSessionId(String sessionId)
{
    return getSessionIdMapping()
            .get(sessionId);
}
```

What I'm doing is not quite right. I am only filtering based on if the `suggestedWord` appears in the query log at all. I need to check and see if it has the word in the right place (the misspelled word in the same location as the correction).

I need a way in `numberOfCorrections`, in the `.map` part of the stream to check and see if the query log has the `suggestedWord` in the same place that `misspelledWord` was in the query. This is where I am stuck. How can I do this?

I'm thinking that it might be something like this:

```
.map(sessionId -> getLogsWithSameSessionId(sessionId)
        .stream()
        .filter(queryLog -> //queryLog.getQuery().equals(some other queryLog in the same session)
        .count()
).count();
```

But I don't know if there is a way to compare to the other `queryLog`s in the same session.

I can't really move on to the second part of my probability until I can figure out how to filter based on if a given query is similar to another query in the same session.

Comment: It appears from your sample list of query logs that the correct words always appear after the mispelled ones. Is this assumption correct? Besides, maybe I'm not fully understanding what you are trying to do, but creating a whole map and filtering for every couple of words your method receives doesn't seem to be the best approach IMO...

Answer (score 2):

It's not easy to interpret your methods one by one. Here is a simple solution:

```
public double countProbability(String misspelledWord, String suggestedWord) {
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(logFilePath)) {
        return stream.skip(1).map(line -> line.contains(misspelledWord) ? misspelledWord : (line.contains(suggestedWord) ? suggestedWord : ""))
                .filter(w -> !w.equals("")).collect(collectingAndThen(groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting()),
                        m -> m.size() < 2 ? 0d : m.get(misspelledWord).doubleValue() / m.get(suggestedWord)));
    }
}
```

I may misunderstand your question.